# It's not about her, because of her?

Tags: prepositions, idiomatic-language

> Jamie: Why are you staying?!? She doesn't care about you. She's
> treating you like garbage.
>
> John:
> **It's not about her.** I am staying because I need to fulfill my purpose.

Do you say "It's not about her"? It doesn't sound right, but I feel like I've heard this before. I use "It's not about her" to mean "I am not staying because of her", but is it the same? What's the short form for "I am not staying because of her"?

Comment: "it" in this case refers to the entire situation and decision, which is not "about her."

Comment: How would you say it? It's not about it sounds wrong.

Comment: I would say it exactly as written in the quote. "[this decision] isn't about her at all, I [have made this decision] because I need to fulfill my purpose"

Comment: "It's not about her" is also perfectly fine.

Comment: Why is "it's not about her" correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some contexts, **about** can mean something close to **because of** when stating an action's reason or purpose.

[Collins COBUILD senses](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about):

> When you mention the things that an activity or institution is about, you are saying what it involves or what its aims are.
>
> - *Leadership is about the ability to implement change.*

> If you do something about a problem, you take action in order to solve it.
>
> - *Rachel was going to do something about Jacob.*
> - *Of course there may be some problems you can't do anything about.*

John's decision to stay, or act of staying, is **about** some goal he has. He claims he is not staying for her.